# Error creating deciles in RStudio: Error in quantile(vector, probs = seq(0, 1, by = 0.1), na.rm = TRUE) : could not find function "quantile"

Tags: r, vector, data-science, quantile

I am trying to create deciles for my own data, but I kept running into the error above, Error in quantile(vector, probs = seq(0, 1, by = 0.1), na.rm = TRUE) : 
  could not find function "quantile"

I even tried to use the ?decile example:

```
# Scores vector 

scores <- c(1, 4, 7, 10, 15, 21, 25, 27, 32, 35, 49, 60, 75, 23, 45, 86, 26, 38, 34, 67)

# Create deciles based on the values of the vector 

decileScores <- decile(vector = scores) 
decileScores <- decile(vector = scores, decreasing = TRUE)
```

and ran into the same error. I installed StatMeasures package.

Comment: Try `library(stats)` then re-run?

Comment: Your code is working for me on R version 3.6.3 with StatMeasures 1.0. Try restarting R. Alternatively, you could use base R instead `ceiling(ecdf(scores)(scores) * 10)`.

Comment: Thank you! I restarted R Studio and it worked. Unnecessarily frustrating,  but we got there!